# R ggplot2 x axis datetime breaks when data is smaller than break

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting the number of messages received against the time they were received.
For example, my data looks like this (which I read in from a csv):

```
timestamp   count
1398094330  286
1398094340  6279
1398094350  447
1398094360  946
1398094370  719
1398094380  171
1398094390  4
1398094400  42
1398094420  2
```

Generally, the data will span multiple hours throughout the day, but occasionally will be limited to a small window of time like the above example.

Because the data normally spans the day, I have set the breaks for `scale_x_datetime` to `"10 mins"` which works for 99% of my use cases. However, it fails for this case.

I define failing as ggplot does not show any x axis ticks because all of my data happens in an approximately 1 minute window for this day, where as my breaks are 10 minutes wide.

This is clearly not useful because you have no idea when the messages occurred when viewing the resulting ggplot graph.

I have everything else working properly, but can not figure out how to have any sort of x axis tick mark show for this example.

I've looked into pretty, but that does not seem to work for `datetime`. Decreasing the break only makes all the other graphs look messy and illegible.

code snippet:

```
tmp = read.csv(args[1])
tmp$time = as.POSIXct(tmp$timestamp, "1970-1-1", tz="America/New_York")
p = ggplot()
p = p + geom_point(tmp, mapping=aes(x=time, y=count), size=1.5)
p = p + scale_y_log10()
p = p + scale_x_datetime(breaks=date_breaks("10 mins"), labels=date_format("%H:%M:%S"))
p = p + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust=0.5))
p = p + labs(title=paste("Message Count, 10 Second Intervals \n", name))
```

dput:

```
structure(list(timestamp = c(1398094330L, 1398094340L, 1398094350L, 1398094360L, 1398094370L, 1398094380L, 1398094390L, 1398094400L, 1398094420L), count = c(286L, 6279L, 447L, 946L, 719L, 171L, 4L, 42L, 2L), time = structure(c(1398094330, 1398094340, 1398094350, 1398094360, 1398094370, 1398094380, 1398094390, 1398094400, 1398094420), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/New_York")), .Names = c("timestamp", "count", "time"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Note: I am using R version 3.0.2

Comment: A `dput` of your data and some "working" code of what you've tried would be helpful.

Comment: Edited code into my post. Unsure of what a "dput" is/does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could include `ifelse()` statement inside the `date_breaks()` that checks how many seconds are between maximal and minimal value of `timestamp` values. If the difference is less than 600 (10 minutes) then `"1 mins"` is used for breaks but if larger then `"10 mins"` are used.

```
ggplot() + geom_point(tmp, mapping=aes(x=time, y=count), size=1.5) + 
    scale_y_log10() + 
    scale_x_datetime(breaks=date_breaks(ifelse(max(tmp$timestamp)-min(tmp$timestamp)<600,"1 mins","10 mins")), 
                     labels=date_format("%H:%M:%S")) + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust=0.5))
```

Comment: This is essentially what I did. I have another program which generates the CSV I was reading into R and I had that calculate what date_breaks to use. Though I may revert those changes and use this solution as it is cleaner.